# Removing with character with condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column of characters with the following format: numeric part (usually 4 digits) + dot + one or two letters. Example: 1111.AA

I want R to remove the first zero whenever the numeric part has 5 digits.

Here is a small sample:

```
df <- structure(list(ID =  c("1111.AA","2222.CC","7891.DD","00111.ZZ","00235.ZZ", "0057.A")), 
.Names=c("ID"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = ("data.frame"))
```

So for example 00111.ZZ should replaced with 0111.ZZ.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the 0 at the start (`^`) of the string followed by four digits (`[0-9]{4}`) captured as a group (`(..)`) followed by a dot (`\\.`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^0([0-9]{4}\\.)", "\\1", df$ID)
#[1] "1111.AA" "2222.CC" "7891.DD" "0111.ZZ" "0235.ZZ" "0057.A"
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the question clearly states that only we need to delete an extra zero in case the numeric part is more than 5 digits long,. so you actually do not need to add the letters this answer given does satisfy the necessary requirements

Answer (score 1):

Similar like akrun's answer, only difference is in REGEX since OP told to cover 1 or 2 alphabets too so covering that part too.

```
sub("^0([0-9]{4}\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,2})","\\1",df$ID)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
> sub("^0([0-9]{4}\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,2})","\\1",df$ID)
[1] "1111.AA" "2222.CC" "7891.DD" "0111.ZZ" "0235.ZZ" "0057.A"
```

Comment: OP clearly stated that only the numeric part should be messed with. The rest eg the alphabets was just but a description of the data.If the data had a wide range, and he wanted to only delete the leading zero, in a string with more than 4 numeric and that had one or two letters, then this would have worked. But that was not the question

Comment: @Onyambu I think this is not messing up the rest of the part as it is included within the capture group

Comment: @Onyambu, thanks for letting me know, if OP confirms that I will delete my answer then to avoid duplicate answer, cheers.

Comment: @akrun. I meant, the numeric part should only be changed. Sure this answer his correct, i was just curious when he said we needed to add the alphabets too as per the comment on your post. So was just trying to say that it is not really necessary to add the alphabets